# Google Apps Account Form won't pre-populate URL query string in iframe

Tags: php, webforms, google-apps

I can not get pre-population to work on an embedded form...

If I use the regular url... it works...
https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/DOMAIN.org/viewform?hl=en&formkey=12345&entry_3=John&entry_4=Doe

but for a google apps account on an embedded form - does not work

Loading...

Form appears in the webpage, but the additional form variables do not populate
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the embedded form is implemented as an iframe within the web-page, thus the variables you're supplying don't make it to the underlying iframe which contains the actual form.

Answer (score 1):

By now you've probably figured out how to do this or found another work around.
I've been looking for a solution to this all day (Christmas 2012).
I finally figured this out and thought I'd post it for others to benefit from.

As pointed out by Onno Benschop in the first answer...
"the embedded form is implemented as an iframe within the web-page, thus the variables you're supplying don't make it to the underlying iframe which contains the actual form".

What I tried was to "Wrap" the iFrame in a Google Gadget.
Wa•La!  It worked.  The Google Gadget passed the pre-populating parameter and populated my multiply choice option.

Here's what to do...

Use the following Google Gadget template.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="Custom Gadget" />
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[

Put your iFrame code here

]]></Content>
</Module>
```

---

Mine looked like this...

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="Custom Gadget" />
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=dGdQcUhDOEl0Z2sxQjUwWnU0all1QkE6MQ&amp;entry_0=Homework+A" width="760" height="1337" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>

]]></Content>
</Module>
```

---

Then save this using a text editor as an XML (*.xml) file.

Next, upload it to the "Cabinet File" that you have on your Google site.

Next, go to you Google Site Cabinet File, locate your iFrame-in-Google-Gadget.xml file.
The word "Download" will be under the file name.
Right click on Download and select "Copy link address".

Now, go back to your Google Site page where you're trying to embed the iFrame.

Open the page editor.

From the top menu select "Insert", "More gadgets..."

In the pop-up window click "Add gadget by URL".

In the Edit Box that pops up, paste the URL you copied to clipboard.

Lastly, click the "Add" button.

A window will appear that allows you to set the "Width" and "Height" of your Google Gadget by pixels or percent.  It also has scrollbar, border, and title options.
Adjust these as needed.

Click the "OK" button.

Now Click "Save" for your Google Site page and the iFrame will be embedded with your pre-populated options!

That's it.  Good luck to anyone else who needs this  :)

John
(MrT@wmsmath.com)